# Find unknown number in array of containing consecutive numbers javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this;

```
var specialOne = 3;
var array = [{value:"special"},{value:"1"},{value:"2"},{value:"specialOne"},{value:"4"},{value:"special"}];
```

And I need to convert it to this array;

```
var temp = [{value:"0"},{value:"1"},{value:"2"},{value:"3"},{value:"4"},{value:"5"}];
```

`special`'s should be replaced with the appropriate value.

`specialOne` should be replaced with the given number.

How can i do this ?

More examples:

```
0,special,2,special,4,5 => 0,1,2,3,4,5
7,8,9,special => 7,8,9,10
special,special,10 => 8,9,10
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want - too confusing.  
You can do this: `for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) array[i].value=""+i;`, but I have a feeling that this is not what you mean/want...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are after

```js
var specialOne = 3;
var array1 = [{value:"special"},{value:"1"},{value:"2"},{value:"specialOne"},{value:"4"},{value:"special"}];
  function addspec(specialOne){
    array1.forEach((o,i)=>{
      if(o.value=="specialOne")o.value = specialOne.toString()   
      if(o.value=="special") o.value = array1[i-1]?(parseInt(array1[i-1].value)+1).toString():"0"
    })
  }
  addspec(3)
console.log(array1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```js
var specialOne = 3;
var array = [
  { value: "special" },
  { value: "1" },
  { value: "2" },
  { value: "specialOne" },
  { value: "4" },
  { value: "special" }
];
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i].value == 'specialOne') {
    array[i].value = String(specialOne);
    console.log(array);
  } else if (array[i].value == 'special') {
    array[i].value = String(0);
    array.pop()
    array.push( { value: String(5) } );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   if (array[i].value === "special") array[i].value = i.toString();
   if (array[i].value === "specialOne") array[i].value = specialOne.toString();  
};
```

When you need to modify an array you should try to use a 'for' loop first. It is the most efficient as it will not modify the index of the array and will not return a new array (Imagine you have to 10 000 items to modify in your array... ).

Here it's very simple, you itere the array, if the condition match you modify the value (of the array itself).

Comment: Please try to elaborate a bit more on **why** this code works.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
var specialOne = 3;
var array = [{
  value: "special"
}, {
  value: "1"
}, {
  value: "2"
}, {
  value: "specialOne"
}, {
  value: "4"
}, {
  value: "special"
}];

function getValues(array) {
  let counterSync = 0;
  let backCheck = [];
  let inFlow = false;
  let backCheckOnce = false;
  return array.map((m, i) => {
    if (isNaN(parseInt(m.value))) {
      if (inFlow || window[m.value]) {
        m.value = "" + (window[m.value] || (counterSync + 1));
      } else {
        if (i === 0) {
          backCheckOnce = true;
        }
        backCheck.push(m);
      }
    } else {
      inFlow = true;
      // do reverse check only once
      if (backCheckOnce) {
        backCheck.reverse().forEach((x, idx) => x.value = "" + (+m.value - 1));
        backCheckOnce = false;
      }

    }
    counterSync = +m.value;
    return m;
  });
}

console.log(getValues(array));
```

Comment: No, If start with 5, must be example : 5,6,special,8 => 5,6,7,8

Comment: @YavuzSelimÖzmen Updated. The only issue I see is the object should always start with number instead of `special` or `specialOne`.

Comment: @YavuzSelimÖzmen Hey I fixed the first value as `special` also. Do understand the code before using it (_it can be refactored_)